# ssrs report multiple languages in same report

Tags: reporting-services, axapta

Is it possible to have multiple languages in a SSRS report? For exemple, I have a table with multiple columns and I would like that each column have the english label and the french one. Something that would look like this :

Interest rate/Taux d'intérêt       Due date/Date d'échéance         Amount/Montant

We use labels for every texts in the report and every label has english/french translation.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you require.  Are you talking about editing a label?  This is just a text box with text - write in what you require at design time.  If you are talking about data returned from the DB, what data structure are you talking about?  Do you want to display the languages concurrently, or one at a time - if so is this based on a parameter?  Please you edit your question to include the current state, current design and expected output to allow us to provide constructive assistance.

Comment: The data is returned from Microsoft Dynamics Ax and currently, all the labels are in the same language as the user who generated the report, but I would like to display both english AND french labels at the same time, for all the text in the report.

Comment: I would create new labels that contain the English and French words in both languages and use those new labels for the report.

Comment: If you're talking about using a custom table, and this dual-language output  is significant, it sounds to me like you'd classify the text as "data" and not merely display text. If that's the case, I'd consider displaying it like data and using a data provider.  The label idea by @FH-Inway is good too. It all depends on your use case.